# chrome extensions with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a google chrome extension, in the run time it displays 
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-GnVJQ+pfVgD0VXf8ZFlSzgJaDUFRyvpUk++sBrdjNQE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
when I run the code as a html page it works perfectly, but as a plugin in chrome it doesn't

```
<script>
function getinput(welcome)
{   var welcome = document.getElementById('welcome')
    var get = document.getElementById('text')
    welcome.innerHTML=get.value;
    var restore = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print()
    document.body.innerHTML = restore;
}
</script>
```

the manifest file

```
{
"name" : "print plugin",
"version" : "1.0",
"description" : "a simple printing plugin",
"manifest_version":2,
"browser_action" :{
"default_icon" : "icon.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html"}}
```

Comment: Add your manifest.json file

Comment: {
 "name" : "print plugin",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "description" : "a simple printing plugin",
 "manifest_version":2,
 "browser_action" :{
 "default_icon" : "icon.png",
 "default_popup":"popup.html"
 }
}
@Barmar

Comment: Add it to the question.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the content security policy directive.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: @Barmar i added the manifest file to the code .

Comment: You're missing `"content_security_policy": "[POLICY STRING GOES HERE]"`

Comment: should i paste it as it is in my manifest file or there must be any other  information i should add it inside the parenthe ses?!  @Barmar

Comment: You need to replace `[POLICY STRING GOES HERE]` with the correct policy string for your extension.

Comment: Inline javascripts are not allowed in the chrome extension. You must put them in a file and include the file using script tag.

Comment: can i have more help please , because i have no idea about the security side .i followed the content security policy document , but theres alot of things i didn't understand .what should I add instead of [POLICY STRING GOES HERE] @Barmar

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation I linked to above?

Comment: yes ,but i had a little hard to understand some few things .@Barmar